# Can't connect to internet in chroot

Tags: chroot

I can't connect to the internet in chroot. For example, when I run apt update, I get a "temporary failure resolving". I tried copying resolv.conf over but still same error.

Answer (score 7):

This helped me.

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

or

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Comment: I tried this and the output is incredibly strange. It says that the file "/etc/resolv.conf" does not exist even though I put it into the folder that I chroot into.

Comment: "/etc/resolv.conf" is alink.

Comment: to "/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf"

Comment: Turned out that the files from /run/systemd/resolve weren't copied over to the guest system. After copying the files, internet works.

Answer (score 2):

you should creat the folder /run/systemd/resolve with mkdir :

```
mkdir /run/systemd/resolve
```

then you can create the link with:

```
ln -sr /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

after that, type `sud apt-get update`

Comment: "/bin/ls: cannot access '/var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the files from /run/systemd/resolve weren't copied over to the guest system. After copying the files, internet works.